# Magento live.com not receiving order emails

Tags: magento, email

For some reason, users with a live.com and some with hotmail.com address don't receive any order emails from Magento.
I tried to set the setting to separate email and set the return path to true. Still nothing happens. 
Normal email addresses are working correctly.

What can it be?

Comment: Send a test mail to hotmail. Then go into your mail logs (or ask your host to). There will likely be an error message with delivering to hotmail addresses. The error message will tell you what the problem is. In the absence of that, make sure you've set up an SPF record correctly.

Comment: Well, my logs says that all the emails are send successfully. I tried to edit my SPF record from v=spf1 +a +mx -all to v=spf1 a mx ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx mx:domain.nl -all
But, still nothing happens.